# Getting error CS0122: UIToggle.Start() is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

New to Unity and Visual Studio.
I Receive the UIToggle.Start() is inaccessible due to its protection level
Here is the code portion of the errors. What am i missing?! I tried the suggestions in Visual Studio and was no help. Thanks

```
    ((SoundFX)soundFX).ChangeSound (soundOn);
                if (soundOn) 
                {               
Error 1             soundToggle.Start ();
                    soundToggle.Set (false, false);
                }
                if (!ambientOn) 
                {
                    ((SoundFX)soundFX).ToggleAmbient ();
Error 2             ambientToggle.Start ();
                    ambientToggle.Set (false, false);
                }

                ((SoundFX)soundFX).ChangeMusic (musicOn);
                if (!musicOn) 
                {               
Error 3             musicToggle.Start ();
                    musicToggle.Set (false, false);
                }

                ((Stats)stats).UpdateUI ();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
soundToggle.Start ();
```

to

```
soundToggle.start();
```

errors went away